# Blazor with AzureAD Auth, Context.Identity.User.Name is null

Tags: azure-active-directory, signalr, blazor

Only authenticated users can access the application as expected. I need to be able to track users via signalr. For example, if I run a ChatHub type of service, I'd like people to be able to chat using their AzureAD username which should be set automatically and not let people set their own usernames.

The hub always shows Context.Identity.User.Name is null.

```
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

    services.AddTransient<HubConnectionBuilder>();


    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub<App>(selector: "app");
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        endpoints.MapHub<SomeHub>("/SomeHub");
    });
```

Any idea if here is a way to preserve identity information and pass to SignalR?

Answer (score 2):

Inspect your `JWT token` and check its claims. You can past it on http://jwt.ms/ to decode it. Then, look for the claims that are being returned that references the user name (in my case it is `preferred_username`).

Then you can change the default mapping of the `Identity.Name` using this code:

```cs
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "<claim_name_that_returns_username>";
});
```

Comment: When I run fiddler and navigate the blazor app, sign in and all, I never see a JWT Token. I see an AzureADCookie passed around. Something I'm missing here?

Comment: On fiddler, try to find the POST call that has this url: "/<yourTenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/token". Then click on the JSON tab to get the access token. When decoding it, remember to remove the word: access_token=

Comment: It is most likely to be "preferred_username". So, try adding: `options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "preferred_username";`

Comment: I tried with "preferred_username" as you suggested, I wasn't sure the order to configure it so i tried before and after the .AddAzureAd statement, both cases name is still null. I believe this is using Cookie auth and not JWT, if so is there a way to read the username from the cookie, or a way to request a token from AzureAD?

Comment: The order will be after `.AddAzureAd(...)`. The correct claim name will be in the token. Another common one for it is `name`. On fiddler, the host will be login.microsoftonline.com, and the url will have the ".../oauth2/...". You must logout and login to catch it. It will be the call after you type your password and click on "sign in" button.

Comment: In the oauth it seems to be passing me back a cookie. Several key/value pairs including: Set-Cookie: AADSSO=
From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.0

"In a browser-based app, cookie authentication allows your existing user credentials to automatically flow to SignalR connections. When using the browser client, no additional configuration is needed. If the user is logged in to your app, the SignalR connection automatically inherits this authentication."

Just seems like that automatic flow is not working..

Comment: You might be looking at the Headers tab. Click on the **JSON** tab in the response window. Be sure to signout first since this call happens when you type your password.

Comment: I understand. I'm logging out and back in completely and the only token is a flow token. I've seen the access-token you mention but for other AzureAD domains I'm connecting to for other applications. I believe when using blazor authentication through AzureAD it defaults to all cookie-based. Checking all packets to login.microsoftonline.com with JSON selected there is no access-token or any reference to jwt.

Comment: In the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.0#authenticate-users-connecting-to-a-signalr-hub), there is this part about `User.Identity`: In a hub, authentication data can be accessed from the `HubConnectionContext.User` property

Comment: I found this which seems to be relevant:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/11262

Answer (score 0):

My workaround at the moment will be to just pass the username when the connection is created to the hub.

In codebehind (SomePage.razor.cs)

```
public class SomePageBase : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    private HubConnectionBuilder _hubConnectionBuilder { get; set; }

    [Inject] 
    private AuthenticationStateProvider authProvider { get; set; }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var user = (await authProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User.Identity.Name;
        // in Component Initialization code
        var connection = _hubConnectionBuilder // the injected one from above.
            .WithUrl("https://localhost:44331/SomeHub")
            .Build(); // Build the HubConnection
        await connection.StartAsync();
        var stringResult =
            await connection.InvokeAsync<string>("HubMethodName", user);
    }
}
```